Packet Loss in OpenStack Neutron with Open vSwitch
I have an OpenStack deployment using Neutron with Open vSwitch (without DPDK). I’m experiencing packet loss in my virtual machines, but I can’t identify any apparent reasons for this issue.
During troubleshooting, I found that the    traffic reaches the network gateway and also gets to the hypervisor,    but it is dropped by Open vSwitch (OVS)
Environment:

OpenStack deployment method: Koll Ansible
Network configuration:Neutron + Open vSwitch

519535738764037 (9) [swapper/9] 0 [tp] **skb:kfree_skb drop (reason openvswitch/OVS_DROP_LAST_ACTION)**
        __init_scratch_end+0x2d232ad7
        bpf_get_stackid_raw_tp+0x73
        __init_scratch_end+0x2d232ad7
        bpf_trace_run3+0x51
        kfree_skb_reason+0x89
        do_execute_actions+0x345
        ovs_execute_actions+0x48
        ovs_dp_process_packet+0x95
        ovs_vport_receive+0x6e
        netdev_frame_hook+0x1b
        __netif_receive_skb_core.constprop.0+0x280
        __netif_receive_skb_list_core+0x136
        netif_receive_skb_list_internal+0x1c6
        napi_complete_done+0x6f
        bnx2x_poll+0x13b
        __napi_poll+0x2a
        net_rx_action+0x233
        __do_softirq+0xca
        __irq_exit_rcu+0xa1
        common_interrupt+0x80
        asm_common_interrupt+0x22
        cpuidle_enter_state+0xca
        cpuidle_enter+0x29
        cpuidle_idle_call+0xfa
        do_idle+0x78
        cpu_startup_entry+0x19
        start_secondary+0x10d
        secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xe5

(OVS_DROP_LAST_ACTION: OVS packets dropped due to an implicit drop action, for example due to a configured network policy.)
No custom configuration has been made to the openswitch settings.
ovs-vswitchd.log
CPU stat Linux 5.14.0-362.24.1.el9_3.0.1.x86_64 10/16/2024 x86_64 (48 CPU)
12:34:53 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
12:34:53 PM  all    6.76    0.00   17.67    0.09    1.38   12.36    0.00   22.29    0.00   39.45
12:34:53 PM    0    2.31    0.00   12.70    0.07    1.31   33.66    0.00   14.76    0.00   35.19
12:34:53 PM    1    2.94    0.00   17.19    0.08    1.50   15.60    0.00   19.82    0.00   42.86
12:34:53 PM    2    2.78    0.00   15.88    0.07    1.39   20.80    0.00   18.41    0.00   40.67
12:34:53 PM    3    2.88    0.00   16.76    0.07    1.44   16.68    0.00   19.62    0.00   42.55
12:34:53 PM    4    3.42    0.00   19.16    0.07    1.54    8.07    0.00   24.57    0.00   43.17
12:34:53 PM    5    3.38    0.00   19.84    0.08    1.55    5.06    0.00   24.04    0.00   46.05
12:34:53 PM    6    3.56    0.00   19.72    0.08    1.56    6.18    0.00   25.77    0.00   43.14
12:34:53 PM    7    2.25    0.00   11.38    0.05    1.26   38.46    0.00   13.34    0.00   33.26
12:34:53 PM    8    2.99    0.00   17.24    0.06    1.49   15.84    0.00   20.36    0.00   42.02
12:34:53 PM    9    2.82    0.00   16.17    0.05    1.40   20.11    0.00   18.67    0.00   40.78
12:34:53 PM   10    3.40    0.00   19.65    0.08    1.52    5.77    0.00   24.11    0.00   45.47
12:34:53 PM   11    2.21    0.00   11.63    0.05    1.26   37.33    0.00   13.15    0.00   34.37
12:34:53 PM   12   10.61    0.00   19.63    0.12    1.34    4.31    0.00   26.42    0.00   37.57
12:34:53 PM   13   10.52    0.00   19.66    0.12    1.35    4.26    0.00   26.38    0.00   37.70
12:34:53 PM   14   10.57    0.00   19.64    0.11    1.35    4.31    0.00   26.03    0.00   37.99
12:34:53 PM   15   10.52    0.00   19.66    0.12    1.37    4.32    0.00   25.65    0.00   38.36
12:34:53 PM   16   10.82    0.00   19.67    0.11    1.36    4.30    0.00   26.15    0.00   37.59
12:34:53 PM   17   10.72    0.00   19.63    0.11    1.35    4.31    0.00   26.02    0.00   37.85
12:34:53 PM   18   10.56    0.00   19.64    0.11    1.34    4.37    0.00   25.85    0.00   38.12
12:34:53 PM   19   10.61    0.00   19.55    0.11    1.33    4.36    0.00   26.03    0.00   38.01
12:34:53 PM   20   10.81    0.00   19.51    0.10    1.32    4.45    0.00   26.58    0.00   37.22
12:34:53 PM   21   10.51    0.00   19.58    0.11    1.33    4.41    0.00   25.82    0.00   38.24
12:34:53 PM   22   10.60    0.00   19.50    0.11    1.32    4.48    0.00   25.88    0.00   38.12
12:34:53 PM   23   10.51    0.00   19.51    0.11    1.32    4.45    0.00   25.49    0.00   38.61
12:34:53 PM   24    3.05    0.00   17.77    0.07    1.49   12.97    0.00   20.67    0.00   43.98
12:34:53 PM   25    3.55    0.00   19.91    0.08    1.56    5.57    0.00   25.98    0.00   43.35
12:34:53 PM   26    1.79    0.00    7.24    0.04    1.08   44.81    0.00    7.69    0.00   37.34
12:34:53 PM   27    2.32    0.00   11.47    0.04    1.25   38.12    0.00   13.28    0.00   33.52
12:34:53 PM   28    2.93    0.00   16.90    0.06    1.51   16.82    0.00   18.74    0.00   43.04
12:34:53 PM   29    2.20    0.00   11.50    0.05    1.27   38.15    0.00   12.59    0.00   34.24
12:34:53 PM   30    3.02    0.00   17.17    0.06    1.49   15.36    0.00   19.89    0.00   43.01
12:34:53 PM   31    3.41    0.00   19.49    0.07    1.51    5.37    0.00   24.21    0.00   45.95
12:34:53 PM   32    3.53    0.00   19.52    0.07    1.55    6.09    0.00   25.03    0.00   44.20
12:34:53 PM   33    1.78    0.00    7.23    0.04    1.06   44.48    0.00    7.68    0.00   37.73
12:34:53 PM   34    2.36    0.00   12.59    0.05    1.27   32.61    0.00   14.29    0.00   36.83
12:34:53 PM   35    3.37    0.00   19.49    0.07    1.50    5.30    0.00   23.12    0.00   47.14
12:34:53 PM   36   10.65    0.00   19.74    0.12    1.36    4.06    0.00   25.71    0.00   38.36
12:34:53 PM   37   10.62    0.00   19.70    0.11    1.35    4.02    0.00   25.63    0.00   38.57
12:34:53 PM   38   10.82    0.00   19.71    0.12    1.37    4.08    0.00   25.84    0.00   38.07
12:34:53 PM   39   10.69    0.00   19.69    0.11    1.36    4.09    0.00   25.87    0.00   38.19
12:34:53 PM   40   10.57    0.00   19.81    0.12    1.38    4.09    0.00   25.72    0.00   38.29
12:34:53 PM   41   10.74    0.00   19.77    0.12    1.38    4.11    0.00   25.94    0.00   37.95
12:34:53 PM   42   10.98    0.00   19.63    0.12    1.37    4.17    0.00   25.78    0.00   37.95
12:34:53 PM   43   10.70    0.00   19.68    0.11    1.34    4.16    0.00   25.56    0.00   38.45
12:34:53 PM   44   10.31    0.00   19.70    0.12    1.36    4.25    0.00   25.36    0.00   38.89
12:34:53 PM   45   10.75    0.00   19.57    0.11    1.34    4.21    0.00   25.82    0.00   38.20
12:34:53 PM   46   10.70    0.00   19.56    0.12    1.34    4.30    0.00   25.73    0.00   38.25
12:34:53 PM   47   10.73    0.00   19.53    0.12    1.35    4.25    0.00   25.79    0.00   38.


Have you checked MTU across all components?

Yeap, MTU size is 1500 throughout

I also noticed that there is a lot of broadcast and multicast traffic on the network.

We have mtu 1500 as well in the hardware infrastructure, but needed to reduce the mtu within self-service networks to 1422 due to the overhead in ovs.

what about multicast traffic how to prevent it?

According to the docs, it’s probably the vxlan protocol that uses multicast to discover instances in self-service networks: https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/admin/deploy-ovs-selfservice.html
